# How to display 2 output in different windows using C

Tags: c

I want to display output on different window, but how? For example: I want to display " hello world " on the first black screen, and when I press enter button, the old screen will disappear and another new black screen will display "thank you" . Just how to do that in c?

Comment: Which operating system/environment? C by itself has no concept of windows or anything so this is specific to the environment

Comment: C does not have a notion of a screen, either. It only has a notion of an output stream. Therefore, if you want to do things like clearing the screen, you will have to revert to platform-specific functions. For this reason, your question cannot be answered, unless you specify which platform (operating system/compiler) your question applies to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using GUI toolkits to create windows to do these functions, one window will show a Hello World statement and the other will show Thank you statement. I can share one great post related to your question:

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_helloworld.html

Comment: I'm sorry but you are killing flyes with a bazooka, a simple fork + execl(terminal -p "Hello world" ...) and then wait from the parent to print "Thank you" will be enough depending on the OS. Also, AFAIK wxwidgets is for C++ and question is tagged C.